# .htaccess file refuses to load

Tags: .htaccess, debian

I'm trying to set my Debian server to look for .htaccess files, but no matter what I do, nothing works!
I have already tried editing my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file and setting `AllowOverride All` for my /var/www directory, and also checked if "default" was enabled...

I've also inserted into my apache2.conf file the following:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

For some reason it still doesn't work. This is my .htaccess file (tested to work in XAMPP on Windows)

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200

RewriteEngine off

DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
Options +MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not hitting the right Directory.

AllowOverride All should do the trick.

> When this directive is set to None, then .htaccess files are
>   completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to
>   read .htaccess files in the filesystem.
>
> When this directive is set to All, then any directive which has the
>   .htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess files.
>
> The directive-type can be one of the following groupings of
>   directives.

Don't forget to restart your apache after editing your apache configuration, check your file permission. You can also tail your error log.

Also make sure you have the **mod_php** module installed as you're using the php_value command